# Edit html/js code and display output in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteorite

I want to teach a basic programming (conditional statements,loop statements..) to secondary schools. I want to teach them using some games,where left side code exists and right side the output displays.Whenever user edits the left side code and press submit, right side output will be displayed.

I want something like in w3schools or jsfiddle.

Suggest something how to do it.

Is there any embedable editors like this or is there any API where we forward our code on button click and take the output and display it in frame.Is there any open-source project like this,so i can fork it and modify according to my reqs.

### I want to develop this in meteor.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about meteor

But if it's a JS library...
[http://repl.it/](http://repl.it/languages/JavaScript) has a javascript mode (a bit like your examples above) and perhaps you could just include the library as the first line of code?

Comment: Meteor is a framework based on Node.js, so it won't be possible to put it inside repl.it sadly. Though, for this purpose, [repl.it](http://repl.it/languages/JavaScript) and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) are great tools on their own, for basic loops Meteor is not necessary.